# While Mysql no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, mysql

No funciona, no sé por qué, pero si hago print_r, todo parece correcto.

```
<?php

 $db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "123", "123", "123");
 $posts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM matposts ORDER BY id DESC");

 while ($row = $posts->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row["id"]." Title: ".$row["title"]." Text: ".$row["text"].'<br>';

 }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el print_r, creo que todo está bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que los campos de la tabla tienen la inicial en mayúscula.
intenta cambiando $row["id"] a $row["Id"] y así con el resto

Comment: Ahhh que idiotaaa, gracias. En realidad no me di cuenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner los campos como aparecen en tu tabla de MySQL

Title en vez de title. etc. los campos son case sensitive

```
 while ($row = $posts->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row["Id"]." Title: ".$row["Title"]." Text: ".$row["Text"].'<br>';
 }
```